# Using limit and offset in addition to pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, pagination, kaminari

I would like to offset my records and then limit the total number of records that will be queried with something similar to the below.

Would anybody have suggestions how to go about it?

`@document_texts = Texts.where(active: true).reorder(created_at: :asc).limit(x).offset(y).page(params[:page])`

Answer (score 1):

Use page & per for the [kaminari](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari) gem

```
@document_texts = Texts.where(active: true).reorder(created_at: :asc)
                       .page(params[:page]).per(50)
```

When `params[:page] = 2` it will fetch records from 51 to 100.

Comment: Thanks, what if I want to only paginate from 51 to 200 (per 50) out of a total of 1000 records?